# Boot MacBook to Linux/Windows from TimeCapsule.

Tags: network, wifi, time-capsule, multi-boot

I love to run different OSs in my 13" Retina MacBookPro. If I can install Windows/Linux/OSX on the Apple TimeCapsule and can Boot them over network wirelessly It will be awesome. If its possible please let me know how to do that. I will go and get one TimeCapsule.

If https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3816843?start=0&tstart=0 is the solution, Please elaborate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple TimeCapsule doesn't offer netboot/netinstall services. None of the essential requirements for such services like NFS (Linux/OS X), http(s) (OS X) or tftp (Linux/Windows) run on the Time Capsule.

You need Mac OS X Server, a NAS/Linux server or a Windows Server (I think some pimped Windows Client OSs will do it also) to accomplish this.

Comment: Shall I go with Linux Server?

Comment: I would go Linux, yes: netboot/netinstall of Linux in Linux is trivial, [OS X](http://www.blueboxmoon.com/wordpress/?p=929) and [Windows](http://www.savelono.com/linux/how-to-install-windows-7-over-a-network-using-linux-pxe-dnsmasq-and-samba.html). But I don't know if it's possible to netboot a MacBook (Pro) to Linux/Windows. Probably you have to search here for q/a or ask a second question.